# Is there a way to get rid of the help messages in git status?

Tags: git

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

This is some of the output when running `git status`.

I don't mind the "Changes not staged for commit:" message, but I don't want to see "help" commands about how to "update what will be committed" etc, as they just add a lot of noise.

I know about `git status -s`, but that's not what I really want.

Is there any way of getting rid of the help messages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the [`git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) documentation you can find the variable `statusHints` of the subsection `advice.*` which is explained like this:

> **statusHints**
>
> Show directions on how to proceed from the current state in the output of git-status(1), in the template shown when writing commit messages in git-commit(1), and in the help message shown by git-checkout(1) when switching branch.

So I would assume setting

```
$ git config advice.statusHints off
```

should get rid of these messages (for the local repository, use `--global` for all repositories of the current user on this machine)

Comment: this has no effect. I tried adding both `statusHints = false` and `statusHints = off` in the `[advise]` section og my config.

Comment: @400theCat what version of git are you on (`git --version`)?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - 'git version 2.20.1'

Comment: @400theCat check your spelling of `[advice]`?

Comment: @Josh Klodnicki - you are right! Using `[advice]` works. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Those help messages were added in Git 1.5 (Q1 2007)

<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4d22965](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d229653ab5eda48f7b7c83cb2a876b48a41ffd4), 11 Jan 2007)</sup>

> ### [`git-status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d229653ab5eda48f7b7c83cb2a876b48a41ffd4): wording update to deal with deleted files.

> If you do:
>
> ```
> $ /bin/rm foo
> $ git status
> ```
>
> we used to say "[`git add ...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4d229653ab5eda48f7b7c83cb2a876b48a41ffd4/Documentation/git-add.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup>
> to add content to commit".
> But suggesting "`git add`" to record the deletion of a file is simply insane.
>
> So this rewords various things:
>
> - The section header is the old "`Changed but not updated`", instead of "`Changed but not added`";
> - Suggestion is `"git add ..." to update what will be committed"`, instead of "`...  to add content to commit`";
> - If there are removed paths, the above suggestion becomes `git add/rm ... to update what will be committed`";
> - For untracked files, the suggestion is `"git add ..." to include in what will be committed"`.

Then with Git 1.6 (Q4 2008), the header generation evolves:

See [commit 4d6e4c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d6e4c4d34435c777bd844fe5ee0ec1ca06ffa4a), [commit bb914b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb914b14c9d2c1c630512291fe4ca276e69b6e00) (08 Sep 2008) by [Anders Melchiorsen (`amelchio`)](https://github.com/amelchio).
<sup>(Merged by [Shawn O. Pearce -- `spearce` --](https://github.com/spearce) in [commit 6ef1daf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ef1daf77202aee71056771d91dd12121c6061fd), 25 Sep 2008)</sup>

> ### [`wt-status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb914b14c9d2c1c630512291fe4ca276e69b6e00): Split header generation into three functions

> Reorganize header generation so that all header text related to each block is in one place.
>
> This adds a function, but makes it easier to see what is generated in each case.
> It also allows for easy tweaking of individual headers.

It now calls [`wt_status_print_dirty_header`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bb914b14c9d2c1c630512291fe4ca276e69b6e00/wt-status.c#L73-L83)

... until Git 2.11 (Q4 2016), which enhances "[`git status --porcelain`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00d27937bf0348e7da615f04b65f535a58e096c1/Documentation/git-status.txt#L35)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---porcelainltversiongt))</sup> output by collecting more data on the state of the index and the working tree files, which may further be used to teach `git-prompt` (in `contrib/`) to make fewer calls to git.

See [commit 888525d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/888525d7865fbf9a277ef5fb8c1fe57f2fb1a0c5) (12 Aug 2016), [commit b249e39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b249e39f9934e020e1cf5e483c3f6f84d3638b31), [commit 1cd828d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cd828ddc8a61f6bec93303f4bdbcdbf1c261cb7), [commit d9fc746](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9fc746cd77910a7dec53abfec36df5c699b33c2), [commit 24959ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24959bad5dba353497323f10b3bf39f243c0f174), [commit 1ecdecc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ecdecce621009a4d039d061d514056501d0ed8f) (11 Aug 2016), and [commit c4f596b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4f596b98ed305ceb594857fa34524fedc30a031), [commit be7e795](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be7e795efe35d3e50199af5452b218e5121b1713), [commit 957a0fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/957a0fe2e59343f10f10620fab787f7e5abf3ab8) (05 Aug 2016) by [Jeff Hostetler (`Jeff-Hostetler`)](https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 00d2793](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00d27937bf0348e7da615f04b65f535a58e096c1), 08 Sep 2016)</sup>

> ### [`status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/957a0fe2e59343f10f10620fab787f7e5abf3ab8): rename long-format print routines
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>

> Rename the various `wt_status_print*()` routines to be `wt_longstatus_print*()` to make it clear that these routines are only concerned with the normal/long status output and reduce developer confusion as other status formats are added in the future.

The current (Aug. 2021) code of [`wt_longstatus_print_dirty_header`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c4203212e360b25a1c69467b5a8437d45a373cac/wt-status.c#L228-L236) show

```c
static void wt_longstatus_print_dirty_header(struct wt_status *s,
                         int has_deleted,
                         int has_dirty_submodules)
{
    const char *c = color(WT_STATUS_HEADER, s);

    status_printf_ln(s, c, _("Changes not staged for commit:"));
    if (!s->hints)
        return;
```

The `if (!s->hints)` part comes from Git 1.8.5 (Q4 2013), from the commit log template, which removes irrelevant "advice" messages that are shared with "[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b4980c63acad8457fb3606b9bd8b74d5e7cba8dd/Documentation/git-status.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> output.

See [commit ea9882b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea9882bfc4d2850b65eac29ac5152e0d778a744b), [commit 6a964f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a964f57e52bb25d9233ff6d38c82a16f21f60aa), [commit 5c25dfa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c25dfaa794c7bbfa1b4d234b10f94ee371b1db0) (12 Sep 2013) by [Matthieu Moy (`moy`)](https://github.com/moy).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b4980c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4980c63acad8457fb3606b9bd8b74d5e7cba8dd), 20 Sep 2013)</sup>

> ### [`wt-status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a964f57e52bb25d9233ff6d38c82a16f21f60aa): turn `advice_status_hints` into a field of `wt_status`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matthieu Moy</sup>

> No behavior change in this patch, but this makes the display of status hints more flexible as they can be enabled or disabled for individual calls to [`commit.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a964f57e52bb25d9233ff6d38c82a16f21f60aa/commit.c):run_status().

That does use the option `advice.statusHints` introduced with Git 1.6.5 (Q4 2009)

See [commit edf563f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edf563fbaa2ab50734db4a61e9092f25fbb5a417), [commit 7519443](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75194438f412714f4e82ca01e9038dc6714498c4) (09 Sep 2009) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dc1b0c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc1b0c06ee9b3d2fb086a89e5b12da35bf360e4c), 13 Sep 2009)</sup>

> ### [`status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edf563fbaa2ab50734db4a61e9092f25fbb5a417): make "how to stage" messages optional
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> These messages are nice for new users, but experienced git users know how to manipulate the index, and these messages waste a lot of screen real estate.

`config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/edf563fbaa2ab50734db4a61e9092f25fbb5a417/Documentation/config.txt#L125-L128):

> ### `statusHints`
>
> Directions on how to stage/unstage/add shown in the
> output of [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) and the template shown
> when writing commit messages. Default: true.

If confirm that with the latest Git 2.33 (in my case git version 2.33.0.windows.2), this option works:

```sh
C:\Users\vonc\git\git>git -c "advice.statusHints=off" st
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
        aFile
```

As opposed to:

```sh
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        a
```

Comment: This history is interesting, but imo a bit long-winded for a simple question with a straightforward answer.

Comment: @Josh Klodnicki - exactly what I was thinking. I got lost in the details. I just want a solution that works, not a story.

Comment: @400theCat So `git -c "advice.statusHints=off" status` does not work? What is your GIt version?