# Advice line does not get printed in Git

Tags: git

On some machines, the line `(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)` does not get printed, where does it come from? what should I do to make it print this **advice** message?

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

renamed:    README.md -> README
```

Comment: Maybe that output is only generated by certain versions of `git`?

Comment: Did my answer help you fix your problem? If so, consider accepting.

Comment: Didn't help on it version 1.9.1, but on other git versions. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

```
git config advice.statusHints
```

See "[Is there a way to get rid of the annoying help messages in git status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110503/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-the-annoying-help-messages-in-git-status)" for a tiny bit more information (and further links)